# edit php code in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am a beginner in wordpress then in my code below, I have an Array of video ids and I use integrated vimeo videos on a page.
    The video starts playing as soon as the page is open and when the first video has finished, the second one starts. 
    Now, I want to add a text field in my wordpress to give permission to user to edit the ids if he want to change the videos.
    Any ideas ?

```
<div id="headervideo" class="videoClass"></div>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

        var videos = [ '240466644', '146661000']; //Array videos ids
        var options = {
            id: videos[0],//first element
            width: 700,
            height: 500,
            loop: false
        };
        player = new Vimeo.Player('headervideo', options); 
        player.play()
        playMovie(videos, 0, true) 
    })

    var playMovie = function(videos, currentVideoIdx, first) {

    if (!first) {
        player.loadVideo(videos[currentVideoIdx % videos.length]).then(function(id) {
            player.play()
        }).catch(function(error) {});

        player.on('ended', function() {
            playMovie(videos, ++currentVideoIdx, false)
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How should the user know the ids? Don't you want to add a select instead of an input?

Comment: yes it's make sense, I think it's the best way ... my videos are on vimeos ....is it problem??

Comment: No, shouldn't be a problem. That is why you use the vimeo player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered writing this functionality as a custom shortcode? Then, you can allow your administrative user to change the video ID's by modifying the shortcode attributes.

For example, let's say you put your functionality in a shortcode, and that shortcode was accessed with the value: **two_videos**

You could modify your functionality to allow for user input/modification of your shortcode, so your end shortcode would look like:

[two_videos video1='240466644' video2='146661000']

That way, your admin user could just change the values of parameters **video1** and **video2**, and you can achieve your desired result.

Comment: You shouldn't need to. You would need to re-write it to be able to be used as a shortcode. Do you have access to the functions.php file of WordPress to make your code a shortcode?

Comment: yes I have access to the functions.php .... I read  about shortcake something like :

Comment: <?php function shortcode_video($param) {
        extract(
                shortcode_atts(
                        array(
             
   'video1' => '240466644',
   'video2' => '146661000',
                     
                        ), $param )
      );
   }
     ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can't allow the user to edit ID and due to security reasons, in simple no one does it. But you can call a string function get user input and then push the string value to the function(i.e., the id array) by calling it. But, not sure until you give more details. What you are trying to achieve.

Comment: so, I want it to be possible to change the videos without having access to the code only in wordpress ...is it possible ??

Comment: Change the video what you mean playing another video with a different id.

Comment: exactly ....for exemple TO DAY I have this video in my web site : var videos = [ '240466644', '146661000']; but another day i want to play other video with this ids var videos = [ '111122222', '333344444'];

Comment: The best way is to use the database to pull value each day and display it and you want to code it for sure. Otherwise, search whether some plugins are available.